# check if id1.1 in 'table1' equal to id1 in 'table2', then insert from the row from 'table1' to 'table2', and same with if id1.1 equal to id2

Tags: r, equals, matching

[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4r4W.png)

[Table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGLH3.png)

> if id1.1 numbers in *Table1* **equal** to id1 numbers in *Table2*,
>   then add to *Table2* the content of the row
>   (fname_c1,fname_c2,lname_c1,lname_c2,by,bm,bd) from the *Table1* that
>   matches.

And

> if id1.1 numbers in *Table1* **equal** to id2 numbers in *Table2*,
>   then add also to *Table2* the content of the row
>   (fname_c1,fname_c2,lname_c1,lname_c2,by,bm,bd) from the *Table1* that
>   matches.
>
> **for example:** (if id1.1=1 in *Table1* and id1=1 in *Table2* (which is
>   id1=id2=1), then add to *Table2* the columns
>   (fname_c1,fname_c2,lname_c1,lname_c2,by,bm,bd) with their rows that
>   matches from *Table1*and if id1.1=55 in *Table1* and id2=55 in *Table2*
>   (which is id1.1=id2=55), then add also to *Table2* the columns
>   (fname_c1,fname_c2,lname_c1,lname_c2,by,bm,bd) with their rows that
>   matches from *Table1*.
>
> (my data is a big dataset so I can't add by typing for example
>   c("FRANK") for each match so that why I want to transfer the content
>   of *table1* to *table2* by matching them by ids ).

[here is an example of Final result how will look like: *Table2* after adding the matches from *Table1*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqR4J.png)

## Table1:(you can run the code from):

```
library(RecordLinkage)
data("RLdata10000")
RLdata10000$id1 <- c(1:10000)
RLdata10000 <- RLdata10000[,c(8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)]
```

## table2

```
library(RecordLinkage)
data("RLdata10000")

rec.pairs <- compare.dedup(RLdata10000
                          ,blockfld = list(1,4, 5:7)
                           ,strcmp =   c(2,3,4)
                           ,strcmpfun = levenshteinSim)


kmeans.model <- classifyUnsup(rec.pairs, method = "kmeans")
summary(kmeans.model)

final.results <- kmeans.model$pairs
final.results$prediction <- kmeans.model$prediction
head(final.results)
only_match_un<-final.results[final.results$prediction == 'L',]

#you will need this for table2
unsupervised<-subset(final.results, select = -c(fname_c1, fname_c2, lname_c1, lname_c2, by, bm, bd,is_match))
names(unsupervised)[names(unsupervised) == "prediction"] <- "links"
```

Comment: can you use `dput` to show the example instead of images thanks

Comment: Using `dplyr`: `new_table <- left_join(table1, table2, by = c("id1" = "id2"))`